# JS: Check boxes Linked to Span & Background Color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two checkboxes (see below) that when clicked, activate a change in background colour of a span. The problem is, I need it such that only ONE of these checkboxes can be activated, while the other one gets de-activated. I know all about radio buttons, the issue is that even when the radio button deactivates, it does not remove the background color of the span. I need a solution that allows ONLY ONE to be selected, and automatically removes the background colour when another option is selected.

Example:
http://eblacksmith.com/test/

Core code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("span[class='checkbox']").addClass("unchecked");

    $(".checkbox").click(function(){

        if($(this).children("input").attr("checked")){  
            // uncheck
            $(this).children("input").attr("checked", false);
            $(this).removeClass("checked");
            $(this).addClass("unchecked");
        }else{
            // check
            $(this).children("input").attr("checked", true);
            $(this).removeClass("unchecked");
            $(this).addClass("checked");
        }

        //alert($(this).children("input").attr("checked"));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   // get a list of all the checkboxes
   var $checkboxEls = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

   $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(event) {

     // highlight this check box
     $(this).parent('span').addClass('checked');

     // remove other classes
     $checkboxEls.not(this).removeAttr('checked').parent('span').removeClass('checked');

   });
 });
```

It makes use of [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to remove the current checkbox from the list of checkboxes we stored earlier. [Example here](http://cdpn.io/IgJwj)

Comment: Is it possible to tailor this to only de-activate checkboxes with the same name property?

Comment: You should never have form elements with the same names as the value of the last one in your html will override previous values.